# sftp file transfer using python works fine despite this ImportError. How to remove this error?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I have this python function to upload file through sftp. It works fine.

```
def sftp_upload(destination, username, password,
                     remote_loc, source_file):
    import pysftp
    with pysftp.Connection(destination, username,
                           password, log="pysftp.log") as sftp:
        sftp.cwd(remote_loc)
        sftp.put(source_file)

    sftp.close()
    return None
```

The code works as expected. However, I always receive this error at the end `ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down`.

How to remove this error? I'm also puzzled why code runs smoothly to the end despite the error.

In the log file, I saw the following;

```
INF [20220304-18:49:14.727] thr=2   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] sftp session closed.
DEB [20220304-18:49:14.727] thr=2   paramiko.transport: [chan 0] EOF sent (0)
DEB [20220304-18:49:14.728] thr=1   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
```

Here's the stack trace;

```
Exception ignored in: <function Connection.__del__ at 0x000001A8B08765E0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 1013, in __del__
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 795, in close
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

I am using python v3.9

Comment: You don't need `pysftp.close()`, that's done automatically by `with`.

Comment: Also, note that the signature of [pysftp.Connection](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-76) is `host, username, private_key, password, ...` - meaning that your function calls it incorrectly as it supplies the password as private key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>*Note: `import pysftp` outside the function somehow resolves the issue for me.*</sub>

---

It's a bug in `pysftp==0.2.9`.

You can fix it by overriding `close()` to only run once:

```py
class SFTPConnection(pysftp.Connection):
    def close(self):
        if getattr(self, '_closed', False):
            return
        self._closed = True
        super().close()
```

Usage:

```py
# with pysftp.Connection(destination, username, password=password, log="pysftp.log") as sftp:  # -
with SFTPConnection(destination, username, password=password, log="pysftp.log") as sftp:       # +
```

References:

- [https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c07917/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-795](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/1c0791759688a733a558b1a25d9ae04f52cf6a64/pysftp/__init__.py#lines-795)
- https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1948
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737761/upload-file-to-sftp-directly-without-storing-it-into-local-system/68738689#68738689](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68738689/8601760)

Comment: your solution to place `import pysftp` is the simplest and most elegant solution. Bounty given to you :). Upvoted and marked as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Any plausible explanation why placing `import pysftp` outside the function solves the problem?

Comment: No, somehow it just causes the [frame object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects), which holds a reference to the `sftp` connection, to not be tracked after the function call.

Comment: I see. The error is still there but just not displayed.

Comment: No, the error is not there because the object is released as soon as there are no references to it, instead of when the program ends. You can observe this with `print('close')` in the overridden method and `print('sftp_upload')` after calling `sftp_upload()`. In the error case, it's `close sftp_upload close` instead of `close close sftp_upload`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your program ends before the `sftp` object is garbage-collected.
Then, the `sftp.__del__` method is called at the middle of the program's teardown, which is causing the error.

From [pysftp.py](https://github.com/ryhsiao/pysftp/blob/685231499b2aea897b01cab370d847907647e40b/pysftp.py) code:

```
def __del__(self):
    """Attempt to clean up if not explicitly closed."""
    self.close()
```

I personally think that it should be considered as a bug in the *pysftp* project.

**I can think of two workarounds:**

1. Override the `__del__` method:

   `pysftp.Connection.__del__ = lambda x: None`
2. (Less recomended - less efficient) Explicitly delete the `sftp` object and trigger garbage collection:

   `del sftp; import gc; gc.collect()` right after the `with` block